# Mark the web as obsolete to force browsers reload its content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working in a dashboard, built in angular, that attacks a backend implemented in java.

I have never worked with angularjs before.

When implementing new features on the frontend and deploying them people need to "hard refresh", in mac, Cmd+Shift+R for Chrome, in order to see the new features.

so far I added this in the meta of the index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-STORE">
```

But it's not working.

Do you know if angular has some directive, some versioning I can use in order to tell the browser, is time to reload the contents?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you talking about updated resources, like javascript files or stylesheets? Or the HTML itself?

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with Angular. Browsers, by default, cache resources for performance reasons. You should do some research on this. A simple search would reveal the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way I've used to ensure browsers pull updated copies of resources is to append a unique querystring value to the URLs. When it's time to tell the browser to re-pull, just change the querystring value.

This syntax would be slightly different depending on your server technology (I'm not very familiar with JSP), but in ASP.NET it would look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?v=<%= Conf.StaticKey %>"></script>
```

In your code, you could point to your app configuration, and pull a key from there, then just change that key in the config when it's time for a new version:

```
public static class Conf {
    public static string StaticKey { 
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["staticKey"]; }
    }
}

<appSettings>
    <add key="staticKey" value="B0DFAB04-33DC-40E7-9E9F-6619CA6441EA" />
</appSettings>
```

When the config value changes, the rendered HTML will show a different query string, and so the browser will re-pull the javascript file. The actual query string value is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid resource caching (such as JS or CSS files) you can add the version number of your angular app to their url

```
http://example.com/v1.2.3/js/myjsfile.js
```

in this way as soon as a new version of your app is released the url will change and the browser will download the file again.

For development consider adding a timestamp to such urls instead of the version number

```
http://example.com/dev/js/myjsfile.js?123124325435
```

If you want to avoid caching also for the HTML files consider sending no-cache headers to the client

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Here you can find a full post about it ([How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers))

Be aware that on production disable caching can overload your server.